# What are the hardwares used to protect against a DDoS attack on Network layer

Tags: network, ddos

What hardware is used to prevent a DDoS attack on a network layer?

This question is for my project which I am doing. I have a game server and I need to simulate an attack - an SYN flood. So what hardware should I use to prevent it.

My assumption is that to place a IDS after a firewall so that it will detect unwanted traffic and filter it out. Also IP filtering method can be used for example bogon filtering.

Please let me know if these assumptions are correct, and if you have more info.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to prevent a distributed denial of service using a single appliance. The problem with a denial of service is that **once the traffic reaches you it's too late**.

The only way to mitigate the risk of a DDoS is to use DDoS mitigation services offered by companies like Rackspace,  Akamai  or Cloudfare. They actually scrub the traffic and check it's origin before it reaches you preventing illegitimate traffic from reaching your server. To successfully deploy such a service you need multiple datacenters across different countries to be able to check the legitimacy of the originating traffic using BGP.

This is why a single appliance at the entry point of your network doesn't suffice.